# How To Subtract On DateTime Object From Another DateTime and Get The Minutes in +N or -N

Tags: php, string, datetime, time, dateinterval

I am making an attendance system. i need help in getting the late person. difference give me only difference no -N or +N

```
$ClockIn = "2019-08-29 06:45:00.000000";
$OpeningTime= "2019-08-29 07:00:00.000000";
$LateTimeDifferenceInMinutes = ($OpeningTime->diff($ClockIn))->i;
$LateTimeDifferenceInMinutes = 15; 

$ClockIn = "2019-08-29 07:01:00.000000";
$OpeningTime= "2019-08-29 07:00:00.000000";
$LateTimeDifferenceInMinutes = ($OpeningTime->diff($ClockIn))->i;
$LateTimeDifferenceInMinutes = 1;
```

i want to get the minutes in positive or negative that i make sure that the person is late

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `new DateTime()` to convert your string variable to date.

```
$ClockIn = new DateTime("2019-08-29 07:07:00.000000");
$OpeningTime= new DateTime("2019-08-29 07:00:00.000000");
$negorpos =  $ClockIn->diff($OpeningTime)->format('%r');
$diff=  $ClockIn->diff($OpeningTime);

$mins = $negorpos . (($diff->days * 24 * 60) + ($diff->h * 60) + $diff->i);
//output: -7
```

Answer (score 1):

Method1, If you want to get the diff in minutes you can use timestamp

```
  $timestamp1 = strtotime("2019-08-29 06:45:00.000000");
  $timestamp2 = strtotime("2019-08-29 07:00:00.000000");

  echo intval(($timestamp1  - $timestamp2)/60) . "m";
```

---

Method2, You can use `invert` to get the sign, [invert](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) and check the [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/831a9d97cf2f557fd87ad290bf8fc071498b9b5d)

> invert: Is 1 if the interval represents a negative time period and 0 otherwise. See DateInterval::format().

```
  $ClockIn = new DateTime("2019-08-29 06:45:00.000000");
  $OpeningTime= new DateTime("2019-08-29 07:00:00.000000");

  $diff= $OpeningTime->diff($ClockIn);
  var_dump($diff->format("%R%i minutes"));
  var_dump(($diff->invert ? "-" : "") . $diff->i);
```

---

*Note*, [php manual note](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php#113283)

> It is worth noting, IMO, and it is implied in the docs but not
>   explicitly stated, that the object on which diff is called is
>   subtracted from the object that is passed to diff.
>
> i.e. $now->diff($tomorrow) is positive.

Comment: For differences> = 60 minutes are returned incorrect values

Comment: @jspit, it's just a demo for the sign of the result.

Comment: @jspit, I add a simple code to get diff in minutes, check it.

Comment: Method 1 is fine (with the limitations of a date associated with an integer timestamp for 32-bit systems).
Method 2 is not ok. The difference between "2019-08-29 05:45" and "2019-08-29 07:00" is wrong as an example.
I think It is better for such problems to use a DateTime extension class (e.g. carbon, moment, dt)